# Onto function with domain of natural numbers and co-domain of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, logic, integers

I'm trying to find an onto function f: $\mathbb{N}$ → $\mathbb{Z}$

This is a new concept I'm learning, and I'm not sure how this would be written. Just need one clear example so I can practice with other examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take the function $f: \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ to be $f(n)= -n/2$, when $n$ is even, and $(n + 1)/2$, when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Ooh yours is better

Comment: how would you should that f($n$) = 0? Given that $n$ > 0.

Comment: Map the odd numbers to (n-1)/2

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume we can construct $\Bbb N x \Bbb N$

We want to define f: $\Bbb N x \Bbb N \to \Bbb Z $ by $f (n_1,n_2) = n_1 - n_2$

Then we can show for any $z \in \Bbb Z $ there exists $(n_1,n_2) $ s.t. $f (n_1,n_2) = z $